# VNC glitch Mac to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc, vncserver, vnc-viewer

I can connect to Ubuntu 14.04 from my Mac OSX 10.11.4 using VNC Viewer

I'm presented with a black screen and a mouse cursor. When I right click the mouse I see a context menu popout on the remote computer, the keyboard works too.

Why can't I see the remote desktop?

**contents of `~/.vnc/xstartup`**

```
#!/bin/sh

#xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
#export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
#/etc/X11/Xsession
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me WAY too long to figure out and I've tried so many things now that I don't know exactly what did it. Here is the page I was one when it finally fixed:

- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/793727/jetson-tk1-remote-access-issue/?offset=2
- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/785551/embedded-systems/my-jetson-focused-linux-tips-and-tricks/

Here are some other things I remember doing (over weeks):

- upgrading VNC Viewer on the client
- installing `xfce4`
- [dconf-editer and disabling encryption](https://askubuntu.com/a/487267/126057)
- setup incoming VNC connection via `remmina`

Here's my most recent from `history`

```
766  vi ~/.vnc/xstartup 
767  sudo reboot
768  tightvncserver 
769  exit
770  sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver
771  find . -name "xstartup"
772  vi .vnc/xstartup 
773  ls -la .vnc/xstartup 
774  vi .vnc/xstartup 
775  sudo reboot
776  sudo apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
777  vi .vnc/xstartup 
778  sudo reboot
779  sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
780  sudo vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/vnc.conf 
781  sudo reboot
782  export DISPLAY=:0
783  xhost +
784  sudo apt-get install x2x
785  sudo apt-get remove x2x
786  nautilus .
787  nautilus ~
788  cd ~
789  ls
790  gedit 
791  exit
792  sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies gnome-icon-theme-full
793  sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
794  vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/xfce.conf
795  sudo vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/xfce.conf
796  sudo reboot
797  vi .vnc/xstartup 
798  history
```

And contents of some of the files listed above:

**~/.vnc/xstartup**

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

**/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/vnc.conf**

```
[VNCServer]
enabled=true
port=5900
width=1280
height=720
depth=24
```

**/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/xfce.conf**

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=xfce
```

I hope my notes mean you spend WAY less time on this issue than I did.

## Cheers

*#jetsontk1 #mac #osx10.11.4 #ubuntu14.04* #vnc